# Python Dash: How to update same local storage using two callbacks?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Below is my callback for logging into my application when the login button is clicked.

```
@app.callback([Output('local', 'data'), Output('redirect-url', 'pathname')],
              [Input('loginButton', 'n_clicks')],
              [State('usernameBox', 'value'),
               State('passwordBox', 'value'),
               State('local', 'data'),
              ])
def login(n_clicks, username, password, local_storage):
    if local_storage is None or not isinstance(local_storage, dict):
        local_storage = {}

    if n_clicks:
        try:
            if len(username) > 0 and len(password) > 0:
                local_storage['user_token'] = 'bearer '+generate_token(username, password)
                app_layout.update_layout(app)
                # update the local storage and redirects to home page
                return local_storage, '' 
        except Exception as e:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            pass

    # refresh the login page
    return local_storage, '/login'
```

I want to clear my local storage in the similar way when I logout. But I am unable to use Output('local', 'data') as it causes duplication issue. How to clear the local storage without getting into duplication issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dash, you can [only target each `Output` once](https://dash.plotly.com/callback-gotchas). If you want to add a clear button, you would need to add the button as an `Input` of the current callback and implement appropriate delegation logic.

The [`GroupTransform`](https://github.com/thedirtyfew/dash-extensions#grouptransform) from `dash-extensions` provides syntactical sugar via a `group` keyword argument. Callbacks within the same group are bundled into one, enabling you to write code like

```
@app.callback(Output("log", "children"), Input("left", "n_clicks"), group="my_group") 
def left(n_clicks):
    return "left"
    
@app.callback(Output("log", "children"), Input("right", "n_clicks"), group="my_group") 
def right(n_clicks):
    return "right"
```

For completeness, here is a full example tested with `dash-extensions==0.0.41`

```
import dash_html_components as html
from dash_extensions.enrich import Output, DashProxy, Trigger, TriggerTransform, GroupTransform

app = DashProxy(prevent_initial_callbacks=True, transforms=[TriggerTransform(), GroupTransform()])
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button("Left", id="left"), html.Button("Right", id="right"), html.Div(id="log"),
])

@app.callback(Output("log", "children"), Trigger("left", "n_clicks"), group="lr")  # targets same output as right
def left():
    return "left" 

@app.callback(Output("log", "children"), Trigger("right", "n_clicks"), group="lr")  # targets same output as left
def right():
    return "right"
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: DashProxy worked for me for this purpose but for some reason it made other existing callback stop working. That callback which stopped working used to auto trigger whenever the url is changed in the browser using the class name of a div tag that never changes but still triggers during page reload.

Therefore I switched back to original app = dash.Dash() to make it work normally. I don't use local storage anymore. I'm storing the user token in the browser cookie.

Comment: Did you try using only DashProxy, but keeping the "normal" Input, Output, State import?